# FB API friends list Invitation customizable UI

Tags: javascript, api, user-interface, graph

I am trying to make a Facebook Invite list using FB.ui(); 
I am failing trying to fetch the Friends list to invite Data ...
I succeeded with FB.ui() default box but I want to make it customizable ! 
Any possible solutions ?

Note that I am using Javascript FB sdk

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/multi-friend-selector/